# Naming input and output variables after a column for each column in a a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a data frame that is the result of some reshaping with dcast.

I'd like to be able to create a named character variable from each column name except 'id'.

Data:

```
id <- c("123", "345", "789", "234")
c10010 <- c(NA, NA, "789", NA)
c11211 <- c("123", NA, NA, "234")
c10013 <- c(NA, "345", NA, NA)
df <- data.frame(id, c10010, c11211, c10013)
```

A non programmatic example of what I'd like to achieve is:

```
c11211_char <- paste(paste(na.omit(df$c11211)), collapse=",")
```

with the correct output of `123,234`.

How can I get each column name to replace the `c11211` instances in the above?

Comment: Use `lapply/sapply` to do this i.e. `sapply(df[-1], function(x) paste(na.omit(x), collapse=","))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the akrun solution and then [`assign()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assign.html) to define each variable by iterating over all columns.

```
id <- c("123", "345", "789", "234")
c10010 <- c(NA, NA, "789", NA)
c11211 <- c("123", NA, NA, "234")
c10013 <- c(NA, "345", NA, NA)
df <- data.frame(id, c10010, c11211, c10013)

s <- sapply(df[-1], function(x) paste(na.omit(x), collapse=","))
for (c in names(s)) {
    assign(names(s[c]), as.character(s[c]))
}
```

Test:

```
> c10010
[1] "789"
> c11211
[1] "123,234"
> c10013
[1] "345"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `list2env`:

```
list2env(lapply(df[-1], function(x) paste(na.omit(x), collapse = ",")), env = .GlobalEnv)
```

This stores each element of the named list as an object in the global environment, using the names of the list.